# Unexpected behaviour for Groovy 'with' method - variable assignment silently failed

Tags: groovy, closures

I have the following code:

```
import groovy.transform.ToString
@ToString(includeNames = true)
class Simple {
  String creditPoints
}
Simple simple = new Simple()
simple.with {
    creditPoints : "288"
}
println simple
```

Clearly, I made a mistake here with `creditPoints : "288"`. It should have been `creditPoints = "288"`.

I expected Groovy to fail at the runtime saying that I made a mistake and I should have used `creditPoints = "288"`but clearly it did not.

Since it did not fail then what did Groovy do with the closure I created?

Comment: I've got this with your code "Simple(creditPoints:null)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Groovy compiler perspective, there is no mistake in your closure code. The compiler sees `creditPoints : "288"` as [labeled statement](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_labeled_statements) which is a legal construction in the Groovy programming language. As the documentation says, label statement does not add anything to the resulting bytecode, but it can be used for instance by AST transformations (Spock Framework uses it heavily).

It becomes more clear and easy to understand if you format code more accurately to the label statement use case, e.g

```
class Simple {
    String creditPoints

    static void main(String[] args) {

        Simple simple = new Simple()
        simple.with {
            creditPoints:
            "288"
        }
        println simple
    }
}
```

*(NOTE: I put your script inside the `main` method body to show you its bytecode representation in the next section.)*

Now when we know how compiler sees this construction, let's take a look and see what does the final bytecode look like. To do this we will decompile the `.class` file (I use IntelliJ IDEA for that - you simply open `.class` file in IDEA and it decompiles it for you):

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.Closure;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import groovy.transform.ToString;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GeneratedClosure;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;

@ToString
public class Simple implements GroovyObject {
    private String creditPoints;

    public Simple() {
        MetaClass var1 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Simple simple = new Simple();

        class _main_closure1 extends Closure implements GeneratedClosure {
            public _main_closure1(Object _outerInstance, Object _thisObject) {
                super(_outerInstance, _thisObject);
            }

            public Object doCall(Object it) {
                return "288";
            }

            public Object call(Object args) {
                return this.doCall(args);
            }

            public Object call() {
                return this.doCall((Object)null);
            }

            public Object doCall() {
                return this.doCall((Object)null);
            }
        }

        DefaultGroovyMethods.with(simple, new _main_closure1(Simple.class, Simple.class));
        DefaultGroovyMethods.println(Simple.class, simple);
        Object var10000 = null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder _result = new StringBuilder();
        Boolean $toStringFirst = Boolean.TRUE;
        _result.append("Simple(");
        if ($toStringFirst == null ? false : $toStringFirst) {
            Boolean var3 = Boolean.FALSE;
        } else {
            _result.append(", ");
        }

        if (this.getCreditPoints() == this) {
            _result.append("(this)");
        } else {
            _result.append(InvokerHelper.toString(this.getCreditPoints()));
        }

        _result.append(")");
        return _result.toString();
    }

    public String getCreditPoints() {
        return this.creditPoints;
    }

    public void setCreditPoints(String var1) {
        this.creditPoints = var1;
    }
}
```

As you can see, your closure used with the `with` method is represented as an inner `_main_closure1` class. This class extends `Closure` class, and it implements `GeneratedClosure` interface. The body of the closure is encapsulated in `public Object doCall(Object it)` method. This method only returns `"288"` string, which is expected - the last statement of the closure becomes a return statement by default. There is no label statement in the generated bytecode, which is also expected as labels get stripped at the `CANONICALIZATION` Groovy compiler phase.